# Using reduce to sum the price of objects in an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that have a price property, and I'm trying to sum all the prices in the object. I think what's tripping me up is that it's an array of objects so I'm having a hard time accessing the price property.

Here's what's displaying in the console: `0[object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]`

Here's my code:

```
const items = [
    { name: 'Bike', price: 100 },
    { name: 'TV', price: 200 },
    { name: 'Album', price: 10 },
    { name: 'Book', price: 5 },
    { name: 'Phone', price: 500 },
    { name: 'Computer', price: 1000 },
    { name: 'Keyboard', price: 25 }
];
const totalPrice = items.reduce((total, curVal) => {
    return total + curVal;
}, 0);
```

Comment: use `total + curVal.price`, since `curVal` is an object with a property named price - or, `items.reduce((total, {price:curVal}) => {` without changing the rest of the code

Comment: Is the {price:curVal} considered destructuring the object?

Comment: destructure and assigning to new variable name

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there!

```js
const items = [
    { name: 'Bike', price: 100 },
    { name: 'TV', price: 200 },
    { name: 'Album', price: 10 },
    { name: 'Book', price: 5 },
    { name: 'Phone', price: 500 },
    { name: 'Computer', price: 1000 },
    { name: 'Keyboard', price: 25 }
];
const totalPrice = items.reduce((a, b)=> a + b.price,0);
console.log(totalPrice);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because curVal is object, you need use price property by `curVal.price`

```js
const items = [
    { name: 'Bike', price: 100 },
    { name: 'TV', price: 200 },
    { name: 'Album', price: 10 },
    { name: 'Book', price: 5 },
    { name: 'Phone', price: 500 },
    { name: 'Computer', price: 1000 },
    { name: 'Keyboard', price: 25 }
];
const totalPrice = items.reduce((total, curVal) => {
    return total + curVal.price;
}, 0);

console.log(totalPrice);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const items = [
  { name: "Bike", price: 100 },
  { name: "TV", price: 200 },
  { name: "Album", price: 10 },
  { name: "Book", price: 5 },
  { name: "Phone", price: 500 },
  { name: "Computer", price: 1000 },
  { name: "Keyboard", price: 25 },
];

let sum = 0;
items.forEach((el) => {
  sum += el.price;
});
console.log(sum);
```

explanation - 
we set sum initially to zero
then we will loop through the array using foreach and access price property using el.price and calculate the sum